# Ubuntu 18.04 ondrej php7.3 - gives php8.0 as default php

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php7

Ubuntu 18.04 ondrej php7.3 - gives php8.0 as default php

**Error in Magento2.3 / Composer1..**

phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement

What does this mean:

```
-> sudo a2enmod php7.3
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.3:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.3:
Module php7.3 already enabled

-> sudo a2dismod php8.0
Module php8.0 already disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very* easy fix. The problem is in your `composer.json` file, as you likely have this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    ...
},
```

Change that line to:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    ...
},
```

This will allow the project to use either version.

Answer (score 0):

> phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.2)
> does not satisfy that requirement

This means that `phpunit/phpunit` requires a `PHP 7.0`, whereas you have `PHP 8.0.2` installed in your environment.

I would recommend the following set of commands:

1. `CD` to your project's root directory where the `composer.json` files exists.

   ```
   $ cd /home/someuser/myproject
   ```
2. Update all the dependencies based on the relevant PHP version installed on your system with the following command:

   ```
   $ composer update
   ```

This will automatically update your dependencies to the latest stable version based on the relevant PHP version installed on your system (In your case `8.0.2`). Make sure you test the entire system before deploying the changes to production.

Answer (score 0):

If  `sudo a2dismod php8.0` does not disable php8.0 module and you cannot switch php module to php7.4 then you can try following:

```
sudo a2disconf php8.0-fpm
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```